# Sorting through div class via opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm using classes to sort different content, but I'm not actually sure how to apply this sorting.

```
    <div class="class1"><div class="heads">Title</div>
<div class="description"><p>Class 1 Item 1</p></div></div>

<div class="class2"><div class="heads">Title</div>
<div class="description"><p>Class 2 Item 1</p></div></div>

<div class="class2"><div class="heads">Title</div>
<div class="description"><p>Class 2 Item 2</p></div></div>

<div class="class3"><div class="heads">Title</div>
<div class="description"><p>Class 3 Item 1</p></div></div>
```

So let's say the user clicks a button that says 'Class 2'. I want the opacity of everything that is not class 2 to be, say, .5 while class 2's opacity stays at 1. I've tried using .not(), but I'm not familiar with it and most examples use it in conjunction with .siblings(), and I don't want the siblings to fade either. Help? I'm not sure what to do.
Edit: Sorry about the orphan s. ^_^; Fixed them!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `a` tag opening is missing. Fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**http://jsfiddle.net/orjj65g0/7/**

```
$("#container button").click(function() {
    var className = $(this)[0].className;
    $("#container button").each(function() {
      if($(this)[0].className !== className) {
        $(this).next().addClass("op05");
        $(this).next().removeClass("op1");
      } else {
        $(this).next().addClass("op15");
        $(this).next().removeClass("op05");
      }
    });
});
```

With `$("#container button").click(...)` you access every button in `#container`.

`$(this).[0].className` is the class name of the button you have clicked.
After you have clicked the button, you go through every button in the container:

```
$("#container button").each(...)
```

In the container you compare the class names with the clicked class name. If there are not the same, than add the class "op05" to the div after the button and remove the class "op1" from the div after the button:

(Example:

```
<button class="classN">click</button>
<div class="content">div after button</div>

$(".classN").next()...
```

)

Here:

```
$(this).next()...
```

And with all the div's after the button(s), that have the same class name happens the same with the 'opposite' class names.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").not(".class2").css("opacity", "0.5")
```

will set opacity of all divs except for ones with class `class2` to 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a container:

```
$('.container>div:not(.class2)').css('opacity', 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. You have invalid HTML. `a` tag opening is missing. Based on my assumptions, that's how it should look like:

```html
<div class="classX">
    <a href="#" class="heads">Title</a>
</div>
<div class="description">
    <p>Class X Item 1</p>
</div>
```

But it's very unintuitive syntax. What is `.description` content for? I suggest you to rewrite syntax. For example:

```html
<div class="classX">
    <a href="#" class="heads">Title</a>
    <div class="description">
        <p>Class X Item 1</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### 2. You can use `.not()` method or `:not()` selector in jQuery

According to my version of HTML. Let's code!

```js
$("a").on('click', function(){
    var $t = $(this).parent(); // clicked div.class2 for example
    $t.css("opacity", 1).siblings().css("opacity", 1); // undo selection
    $t.siblings().not("."+$t.attr("class")).css("opacity", 0.5); 
    // hide other classes. Equivalent with selector:
    //$t.siblings(":not(."+$t.attr("class")+")").css("opacity", 0.5); 
});
```

Check it that's what you want: **http://jsfiddle.net/Tymek/2k85m8r9/**